# Soap call failed

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have problem with sending my soap to server, get error and cannot get details throw:

```
if (is_soap_fault($result)) {
     trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$result->faultcode}, 
     faultstring: {$result->faultstring})", E_ERROR);
  }
```

becuase it shows nothing

My code looks like:

```
    $customer = $rowDopravaLang['id_customer'];
    $postcode = $rowDopravaLang['postcode'];
    $address1 = $rowDopravaLang['address1'];
    $dic = $rowDopravaLang['vat_number'];
    $ico = $rowDopravaLang['dni'];
    $city = $rowDopravaLang['city'];
    $firstname = $rowDopravaLang['firstname'];
    $lastname = $rowDopravaLang['lastname'];
    $phone_mobile = $rowDopravaLang['phone_mobile'];


    if($rowDopravaLang['company'] != '' OR $rowDopravaLang['company'] != NULL) {
        $company = $rowDopravaLang['company'];
    } else {
        $company = $firstname.' '.$lastname;
    }

     $dorucovaci = (object)array('ISOZeme' => 'CZ',
            'Obec' => $city,
            'Okres' => $city,
            'PSC' => $postcode,
            'Ulice' => $address1);

        $zakaznik = (object)array('AdresaSidlo' => $dorucovaci, 'DIC' => $dic, 'IC' => '', 'FakturacniAdresa' => $dorucovaci,
            'Firma' => $company, '4W-1' => $firstname, 'Prijmeni' => $lastname, 'Telefon' => $phone_mobile, 'Kniha' => 'Eshop', 'NazevFirmy' => $company, 'TypKontaktu' => 'Organizace', 'referent'=>'xxx');

    $url="http://xx.xxx.xx.yy:y/xxxx/Altus.COM.V12.BasicServices.Kontakty?wsdl";
    $config = array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 0);

    $service = new SoapClient($url, $config);



        $result = $service->VlozitKontakt(array("kontakt" => $zakaznik));
```

---

result of already added object is:

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: it: SoapFault exception: [a:BadRequest] Bad Request in /srv/posunemevasvys.cz/drevoobchod/web/export/test-zaloha.php:56 Stack trace: #0 /srv/posunemevasvys.cz/drevoobchod/web/export/test-zaloha.php(56): SoapClient->__call('VlozitKontakt', Array) #1 /srv/posunemevasvys.cz/drevoobchod/web/export/test-zaloha.php(56): SoapClient->VlozitKontakt(Array) #2 {main}